ADV android Studio doesn't show the releases list on the page "System Image" when creatin a new virtual device
When I run the AVD Manager in Android Studio on a Mac and try to add a virtual device, after selecting the hardware, no entries appear on the image selection screen (see attachment), and I haven't been able to resolve this issue. I have tried reinstalling new versions of Android, but I am still experiencing the same problem. Any ideas to overcime this issue? Thanks in advance.
Using:
Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-241.18034.62.2411.12071903, built on July 10, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.1.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 10
Metal Rendering is ON
Non-Bundled Plugins:
com.vermouthx.xcode-theme (1.7.0)
Dart (241.17502)
io.flutter (80.0.2)

